# ¿Cómo generar TOKEN en C# (desde especificaciones JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

Necesitó crear un token, tengo una función JavaScript que lo hace bien pero debo crear un método en C#.

*Construí un método en C# pero aunque no genera error,  no funciona bien como la función JavaScript*

**JavaScript**

```
function SetToken() {
    let iat = new Date();
    let exp = iat + 600 * 60;
    let min = 17592186044416;//Hex 1000000000000
    let max = 281474976710655;//Hex ffffffffffff
    let nonce = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min).toString(16);
    let jwtPayload = {
        iss: "Datos_USA",
        sum: "21abcdef567576abd",
        aud: "APIGateway",
        scope: "App:Read:Write",
        exp: exp,
        iat: iat,
        nonce: nonce
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jwtPayload));
}


**C#**

 

     public  string GenerateJwtToBankCoApi()
{
    var token = string.Empty;
    DateTime iat = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime exp = iat.AddSeconds(600 * 60);
    long min = 0x1000000000000; // Hexadecimal 1000000000000
    long max = 0xfffffffffff;   // Hexadecimal ffffffffffff
    Random random = new Random();
    long randomNonce = (long)(min + random.NextDouble() * (max - min + 1));
    string nonce = randomNonce.ToString("x");
    var  expValue = (long)(exp - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
    var iatValue = (long)(iat - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;

    using var rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportFromPem(ReadFileKeyPem());

    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(rsa), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
    {
        CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory { CacheSignatureProviders = false }
    };

    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(claims: new[]
    {
      new Claim("iss", this._bankColombiaTokenApiSettings.Iss),
      new Claim("sum", this._bankColombiaCredentialsSettings.Client_Id),
      new Claim("aud", this._bankColombiaTokenApiSettings.Aud),
      new Claim("scope","Payment:write:user"),
      new Claim("exp", expValue.ToString()),
      new Claim("iat", iatValue.ToString()),
      new Claim("nonce", nonce)
      },
      signingCredentials: signingCredentials
    );

    var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jwt);

    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

    return token;
}
```

}

Comment: Por curiosidad, por qué necesitas hacerlo en C#? La idea de usar un JWT (por los parámetros que creas) suele ser generarlo en el frontend, y que el backend solo lo verifique  y haga la acción correspondiente... Si el backend necesita llamar a otro sitio, le pasa ese mismo token que ha recibido...

Comment: El código javascript es incorrecto. Cuando haces `let exp = iat + 600 * 60` entiendo que quieres sumar tiempo a la fecha, pero ahí lo único que estas haciendo es una concatenación de strings. Además cuando pasas la fecha al json la haces sin declarar el formato lo cual será distinto según el `locale` del navegador, lo normal es que sea en formato ISO. Por último en C# estás intentado generar un token, cuando en el javascript no hay nada de eso

Comment: Por eso nesecito ayuda

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC Y yo quiero ayudar, pero tampoco quiero perder el tiempo. Si tu confirmas que la función en JS es lo que quieres, no tengo problema en generar la versión de C#. Ahora si es otra cosa lo que necesitas, yo requiero aclaraciones, sobre todo en indicar que datos deben ir en `iat`, `exp` y `nonce` (y en que formato)

Comment: @Yussef fijate que modifique mi pregunta, la  funcion JS crea solo el payload del token que nesecito, el metodo c# debe crear un payload igual a la de lafuncion JS y craer un TOKEN con algoritmo Rs256 firmado con una clave privada que tengo en un archivo de extension .pem